How to generate a multi-page table in a PDF using iText7 in C#?
I'm trying to generate a PDF with a table that spans multiple pages using iText7 in C#. However, I'm encountering an error: "PdfPages tree could be generated only once."
Here is a simplified version of my code:
using (var templateReader = new PdfReader(_env.ContentRootPath + "\\templates\\" + single.Tipo + ".pdf"))
using (var templateDoc = new PdfDocument(templateReader))
{

    PdfPage templatePage = templateDoc.GetPage(1);
    PdfFormXObject templateXObject = templatePage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);

    canvas.BeginText();
    canvas.MoveText(120, 664);
    canvas.ShowText($"{single.Numero} / {single.Data.Year.ToString()}");
    canvas.EndText();

    canvas.BeginText();
    canvas.MoveText(40, 756);
    canvas.ShowText(single.Data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    canvas.EndText();

    canvas.BeginText();
    canvas.MoveText(500, 800);
    canvas.ShowText("ID#" + single.Id.ToString());
    canvas.EndText();

    Table table1 = new Table(1).SetWidth(526);
    var righe = single.Righe.ToList();
    AddPreventivoTable(table1, righe);

    float rectHeight = 595;
    var altezzaRighe = CalculateRowHeights(table1);
    var table1Height = altezzaRighe.Sum();
    int pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(table1Height / rectHeight);


    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            pdfDoc.AddNewPage();
            var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i + 1);
            canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
            var bf = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
            canvas.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
            canvas.SetColor(ColorConstants.BLACK, true);
            canvas.AddXObject(templateXObject);
            AddIntestazione(canvas, ana);

            canvas.BeginText();
            canvas.SetTextMatrix(120, 664);
            canvas.ShowText($"{single.Numero} / {single.Data.Year.ToString()}");
            canvas.EndText();

            canvas.BeginText();
            canvas.SetTextMatrix(40, 756);
            canvas.ShowText(single.Data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            canvas.EndText();

            canvas.BeginText();
            canvas.SetTextMatrix(500, 800);
            canvas.ShowText("ID#" + single.Id.ToString());
            canvas.EndText();

        }

        Rectangle rect1 = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(34, 60, 526, rectHeight);
        var canvasRect1 = new Canvas(canvas, rect1);
        Table subTable = new Table(1).SetWidth(526);
        float currentHeight = 0;
        int currentRow = 0;
        while (currentRow < table1.GetNumberOfRows())
        {
            float cellHeight = altezzaRighe[currentRow];
            if (currentHeight + cellHeight > rectHeight)
            {
                break;
            }
            var cell = table1.GetCell(currentRow, 0).Clone(true);
            subTable.AddCell(cell);
            currentHeight += cellHeight;
            currentRow++;
        }


        canvasRect1.Add(subTable);
        canvasRect1.SetBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY, 0.5f));
        canvas.Stroke();
        canvasRect1.Close();
    }
}`

When I replace the cell creation with a simple cell containing a paragraph, the error does not occur. However, I need to copy the content from the original table cells, which may include nested tables and other elements.
How can I correctly copy the content of the original cells and add them to the new table without encountering this error? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I found the solution by changing my approach. Instead of placing the tables in rectangles, I added the table to the document, allowing it to span across multiple pages automatically. Then, using the SetRelativePosition method, I positioned the table within the document, and with the document margins, I was able to achieve exactly what I needed.
using (var templateReader = new PdfReader(_env.ContentRootPath + "\\templates\\" + single.Tipo + ".pdf"))
using (var templateDoc = new PdfDocument(templateReader)) 
using (var writerDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms)))
{ 
    Document document = new Document(writerDoc);
    document.SetMargins(50, 36, 200, 36);

    bool isAzienda = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ana.PartitaIva);
    Table table = new Table(1).SetWidth(526);
    var righe = single.Righe.ToList();
    AddPreventivoTable(table, righe);
    table.SetRelativePosition(0, 140, 0, 0);
    document.Add(table);

    PdfPage templatePage = templateDoc.GetPage(1);
    PdfFormXObject templateXObject = templatePage.CopyAsFormXObject(writerDoc);

    for (int i = 0; i < writerDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
    {
        PdfPage page = writerDoc.GetPage(i + 1);
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        var bf = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
        canvas.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
        canvas.SetColor(ColorConstants.BLACK, true);
        canvas.AddXObject(templateXObject);
        AddIntestazione(canvas, ana);
        canvas.BeginText();
        canvas.SetTextMatrix(120, 664);
        canvas.ShowText($"{single.Numero} / {single.Data.Year.ToString()}");
        canvas.EndText();
        canvas.BeginText();
        canvas.SetTextMatrix(40, 756);
        canvas.ShowText(single.Data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        canvas.EndText();
        canvas.BeginText();
        canvas.SetTextMatrix(500, 800);
        canvas.ShowText("ID#" + single.Id.ToString());
        canvas.EndText();
    }

    document.Close();

}

